# Text for study of subgroup lattices of finite abelian groups.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, abelian-groups, lattice-orders, reference-works

I want to study the subgroup lattice of a finite abelian group. I have found a text on the subject: Subgroup Lattices of Groups by Roland Schmidt, de Gruyter 1994. This book is about subgroups of any group, not just finite abelian groups.

Is this text a good introduction to the subject? Are there other more accessible texts or lecture notes on the subject? Is it advisable to study a text on lattice theory first, or should I pick up the poset and lattice basics from the proposed text?

Any info regarding introductory texts / notes on the subgroup lattice of a finite abelian group might help.

Comment: Finite only, thanks I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subgroup lattices of finite abelian groups have been studied from various points of view, see the following reference:

Vogt, Frank : *Subgroup lattices of finite Abelian groups*: Structure and cardinality.
In: Lattice theory and its applications. Hrsg.: K.A. Baker, R. Wille. S. 241-259. Heldermann , Berlin .
[Buchkapitel], (1995)